# :before psuedo selector not working ie 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have some CSS that is working in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE 11.

It's a simple horizontal NAV bar with pipe separators.

Here's the CSS:

```css
.language li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.language li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.language li:nth-child(9n+1):before {
        content: '\a';
        position: static;
        white-space: pre;
}
```

And here's the HTML

```html
<ul class="language">
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Español"> Español </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - HMOOB"> HMOOB </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Chinese"> 简体中文 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - DEUTSCH"> DEUTSCH </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Arabic"> العربية </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - gujarati"> ગુજરાતી </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Russian"> РУССКИЙ </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Korean"> 한국어 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Vietnamese"> Tiếng Việt </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Français"> Français </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Polski"> Polski </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Pennsylvaanisch Deitsch"> Pennsylvaanisch Deitsch </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - HRVATSKI"> HRVATSKI </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Tagalog"> Tagalog </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="" target="_blank" title="SSM Directory Language - Hindi"> Hindi </a> </li>
</ul>
```

In Chrome and Firefox it works great, but in IE I get the following without separators or spacing:

```
Español HMOOB 简体中文 DEUTSCH ગુજરાતી РУССКИЙ 한국어 Tiếng Việt Français Polski Pennsylvaanisch Deitsch HRVATSKI Tagalog Hindi العربية
```

Comment: Make sure you have a proper [DOCTYPE](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/04/html5-doctype/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the lastest version of IE? I've testet your code and it seems to run okey in IE 11. I have version 11.576.14393.0.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've verified that it is the latest version of IE